# how to plot markers on graph with different color

Tags: matlab, plot, markers

I now have such code:

```
fDeals = fopen([logsFolder stock '_deals.log']);
data = textscan(fDeals, '%f:%f:%f:%f %f,%f %f,%f %f,%f %f');
fclose(fDeals);

% hh:min:sec:millisec
secvec = [60*60 60 1 1e-3];
x = [data{1:4}] * secvec';

flvec = [1 1e-16];
y = [data{5:6}] * flvec';

ammount = data{11};

xindays = x / (24*60*60);

plot(xindays, y, 'go','MarkerSize',6,'LineWidth',3);
```

It works fine but it always create green marker. I need to create green marker if amount > 0 otherwise I want to create red marker. How to do that?

Likely i should create separate `xGreen`, `xRed`, `yGreen`, `yRed` arrays, but then I need to separate file lines into two groups somehow - lines with >0 amount and lines with <0 amount (amount is never 0).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
markerIDX = ammount > 0;

plot(xindays(markerIDX), y(markerIDX), 'go','MarkerSize',6,'LineWidth',3);
plot(xindays(~markerIDX), y(~markerIDX), 'ro','MarkerSize',6,'LineWidth',3);
```

Note, however, that this only works if `xindays`, `y`, and `ammount` are of the same size.

Comment: i don't understand how, but it works, thanks! what is the result of `~markerIDX`, what is this `~` operation?

Comment: The tilde operator `~` is the logical `not`. In `markerIDX` are all indices where `ammount > 0` holds, and in `~markerIDX` are all indices where `ammount > 0` does not hold, that is, `ammount <= 0`.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the [GSCATTER](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/gscatter.html) function from the Statistics Toolbox:

```
group = ammount > 0;
h = gscatter(xindays, y, group, 'gr', 'o', 6);
set(h, 'LineWidth',3)
legend(h, {'group 1','group 2'})
```